# How to detect child scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We can see that scroll events do not propagate on `overflow:scroll` elements as demonstrated here:

http://jsfiddle.net/vnXm6/

How can we detect **from a parent element**, `scroll` events on child elements?

Comment: Individual DOM elements should trigger their own `.on('scroll')` events.

Comment: but they do not seem to propagate

Comment: You check out my revision bro?

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean, the new .live replacement doesn't work with scroll. This is a crafty workaround though!

```
$("#parent").on("mouseover", function(){

    $('#parent > *').on('scroll', function(){
       console.log('scrolling');
     });
});
```

[**Revised Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/HTUTA/2/)

Comment: this is not from the parent element

Comment: thanks but this is still from the children, you're just adding a parent selector.  I'm looking for a solution where the children may or may not exist, and are dynamically created.

Comment: sorry this is not the type of solution I'm looking for, but thanks

Comment: @Vigrond Then what in the world are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

#### Use this code:

```
$("#parent > #child").on("scroll", function(){
   console.log('scrolling'); 
});
```

You can see the console output, comes this way:

```
scrolling
scrolling
scrolling
scrolling
scrolling
scrolling
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dZ24z/